# MPI_Type_indexed memory layout

Tags: c, mpi

Consider the method [MPI_Type_indexed](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Type_indexed.html). I send/receive elements from an array which are located in a random order. For example, elements in positions of 5, 16, 102, 1001, ... Would it be better if I arrange them adjacent to each other before setting up MPI data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define "better".

It might make your code easier to maintain, in the sense that swapping values in memory and sending them as a single array is arguably easier to do and less error prone than setting up an indexed datatype.

Performance-wise it's pretty unnecessary, unless perhaps you have so many values to pick from that they don't all fit in memory and the OS has to resort to paging. Even then, hard drive access may still be faster than network traffic, so the performance gain might turn out to be negligible compared to the inherent overhead of passing a message. I'm not even considering the algorithmical overhead of sorting your array. Of course, as always, the only true answer to the question "would it be more efficient if I did X instead of Y?" is "profile both and see for yourself".

In short, I wouldn't bother rearranging your data, unless you specifically want to avoid using derived MPI datatypes for whatever reason. Derived datatypes were created for this very scenario.